# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message

Tags: java, logging, log4j

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/logging/log4j/message/Message
    at com.prac.Loger.(Loger.java:34)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 1 more

Exception points to Loger.java:34

```
static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger(Loger.class);
```

Please help me get rid of this exception...

Comment: Is there `log4j.jar` in your classpath ?

Comment: @sanDecruz following 2 jars in classpath:log4j-core-2.1.jar and log4j-1.2-api-2.1.jar

Comment: How did you try to print the log ? Can you show the code ?

Comment: i havent tried printing log .

Comment: it throws exception on mentioned line of code

Comment: Have you tried removing and adding the jar again it seems some files have been corrupted in the jar.

Comment: `ClassNotFoundException` is always thrown on missing and corrupted class file. Add your jars wisely :)

Comment: @ParUpadh You should add your solution as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Added log4j-api-2.1.jar and error is gone.!